# library for solving matrix problems in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Does Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 have a built-in library which can help in solving all sort of matrix problems?

For example:

- Singular value decomposition
- Matrix inversion
- Trace
- Determinants
- etc.

Comment: How fast does it need to be (i.e. how much inconvience will you accept for performance)?  How large are the matrices you expect to spend most CPU-time on (i.e. optimized for large or small matrices)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a built in matrix manipulator for .NET, even if there is a custom library should provide a lot more features.

You could try http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/

Comment: Math.net is a outer source Library right ? So it means Visual studio does not have a class which can solve problems regarding Martix

Comment: As I said, I don't think there is one that comes with .NET

Answer (score 1):

Advanced matrix math is not builtin.  You could try [Extreme Optimization](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/HowToBuy.aspx) on a free trial version - it's expensive but maybe you can get an academic license? or perhaps your company will license if it works for you.  Does not sound so expensive if you work out how long it would take to rebuild the matrix math you need. They might allow you to license only the matrix part at reduced cost.

Comment: Its very sad to hear that MicroSoft didnt not created a built in class for Matrix.So it means the only way to solve matrix issue easily by using outer source  libraries like Math.net etc